# Looking for image in HDD rather in context

Tags: url, jsf, itext, contextpath

I have multimodule project

```
Project
  |--src
      |-JavaFile.java

Web-Project
  |-Web-Content
    |-images
    |   |-logo.PNG
    |-pages
    |-WEB-INF
```

1. regular java module - contains src with all java files
2. dynamic web project module - contains all web related stuff

eventually regular java module goes as a jar file in dynamic web module in lib folder

### Problem

java file after compilation looks for an image file in c:\ibm\sdp\server completepath\logo.png rather in context. File is defined in java file as below for iText:

```
Image logo = Image.getInstance("/images/logo.PNG");
```

Please suggest how can I change my java file to refer to image. I am not allowed to change my project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or, better, [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) for that. It returns an [`URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) respectively an [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) of the resource in the web content.

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo.PNG");
// ...
```

This way you're not dependent on where (and how!) the webapp is been deployed. Relying on absolute disk file system paths would only end up in portability headache.

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you seem to be using iText (you should have clarified that a bit more in the question, I edited it). You can then use the `Image#getInstance()` method which takes an `URL`:

```
URL url = getServletContext().getResource("/images/logo.PNG");
Image image = Image.getInstance(url);
// ...
```

---

**Update 2**: as per the comments, you turn out to be sitting in the JSF context (you should have clarified that as well in the question). You should use [`ExternalContext#getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) instead to get the `URL`:

```
URL url = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource("/images/logo.PNG");
Image image = Image.getInstance(url);
// ...
```

Comment: Question: I need absolute URL or Absolute filename -> String rather stream. I am using com.itextpdf.text.Image;

Thank you very much for you kind reply.
I am using faces therefore I had to use

  InputStream input = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo.PNG");
  Image logo = Image.getInstance(input);

Comment: I do not have direct access to Servlet Context I go through FacesContext. Now I get NullPointerException.
  InputStream input = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("../images/logo.PNG");
  String str=input.toString();
  byte[] b=str.getBytes();
  Image logo = Image.getInstance(b);

Comment: My bad wrong file Name I had...
Now its throwing java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.

Comment: You're using JSF? You should have mentioned that as well :) I'll update the answer. Your mistake is by the way caused because you did a nonsensicial `toString()` on the `InputStream` instead of reading it using `read()`.

Comment: After a search on how to change from inputStream to byte array I was able to resolve the problem. Thanx alot BalusC you are always a great help.